# Ethernet keeps cutting off by server

Tags: ethernet, switch, self-hosting

I am self-hosting a few servers on the attic and for some reason, after a while, the whole ethernet cable running up there cuts off.

I've already narrowed it down to 1 of the pcs on the attic, because when I restart that pc it starts working again.

I'm not really sure what's relevant to post about the server,
But it's running Debian 10
with pm2 a few discord bots and lightweight web apps
MongoDB server
MySQL server
nginx

what could be the issue here, and how would I be able to fix it?

this setup is probably far from ideal, but it is really annoying to keep restarting it.

here's a sketch of how it is connected:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFtTT.png

Thanks!

Comment: "the whole ethernet cable running up there cuts off" so the switches stop talking to each other? Check e.g. unicast flooding ( see for example https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6000-series-switches/23563-143.html ) If it isn't specifically unicast floodding, it is probably something similar.

Comment: not sure if it's that, but if it was how would I fix it?

Comment: If you can identify that as the problem, then you are well on your way to fixing it. I mentioned it and gave something in-depth to read because there is a lot of potential complexity and you'd need to poke around a little. The one server taking out the port between attic and the rest of the lan definitely points to flooding and also the rebooted PC. Start with leaving that off long enough to see if it resolves. If it does, then you have the culprit, look at pc config; otherwise pick another PC and repeat

Comment: after reading it, while I don't completely understand it, it does seem like it could be some kind of flooding, but what could I do about it? thanks for your help up until now by the way!